# C convert char array (string) UTF8 format to CP1252 (ASCII) format

Tags: c, utf-8, format, buffer

I have two C sources files:

1. First file is saved in UTF-8 format
2. Second file is saved in CP1252 format.

**My example message is**: `char mybuffer[] = "lé\r\n";`

In the UTF-8 source file, the string has been encoded using 5 bytes:

```
6C C3 A9 0D 0A
```

In the CP1252 source file, the string has been encoded using 4 bytes:

```
6C E9 0D 0A
```

*I know that the two results are good, because you can set the output format to read correctly the two results.*

But I need to convert the UTF-8 array variable into CP1252 format.

I use only C language.

Comment: see [iconv()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/iconv) -- it's not officially in the C standard library, so depending on your target platform, you might need to link an additional lib. POSIX conforming systems should have it.

Comment: side note, your encoding isn't correct, you're showing the representations of 32bit 2's complement integers that probably resulted from sign extending the actual bytes ... and the `\n` (`0x0a`) is missing completely.

Comment: I use printf("%#08x, ", mybuffer[i]); to trace each hex char stored, and final "\n" is coded by 0x0d

Comment: yes, that's wrong ... both UTF-8 and CP1252 are byte encodings with a byte having 8 bits, so to see the real representation, you'd need `printf("0x%02x", (unsigned char) bufferTMP[i]);` -- `0x0d` is the encoding of `\r`.

Comment: Initial post corrected with good value

Comment: Detail: I would not expect 5 bytes to be `0x00006c, 0xffffffc3, 0xffffffa9, 0x00000d, 0x00000a`, but `0x6c, 0xc3, 0xa9, 0x0d, 0x0a`.  Although, this simply lops off a sign extension - it is more clear.  What tool was used to determine source file contents?

Answer (score -1):

If the files are source code files then you must tell the compiler what the source "charset" is for each. You are possibly doing this by default. If the two files have different encodings, you would probably have to run the compiler separately on each one. If the difference is showing up then you are doing that wrong.

Alternatively, convert source file encodings so they are all the same encoding, to make your project simpler. But, this doesn't get around the requirement to tell the compiler the correct encoding(s). *This applies to opening any text file with any program or communicating it to someone else.*

Comment: Thx for your answer, but I have used example of source file to understand  easily the problem. Infact I cannot choose correct encoding format to compiler or in/out informations. I know just my message is badly encoded.